# mongodb 3.0.4 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS configuration file not yaml?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using mongodb 3.0.4 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I wanted to change the dbpath in /etc/mongod.conf. However after checking the mongodb manuals, I read that the configuration file format was changed to YAML after version 2.6. But my configuration file doesn't look like this. Did I missed anything or is it a bug or should I change the conf file to YAML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what format is your config file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config files old format (which is a series of `settings=values` separated by new lines) is still usable, but deprecated.  It will eventually be removed, and certain new settings (like [Storage Engine](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-options) options) may not be configurable.  I would recommend switching to the [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) format as soon as you can for future-proofing.

The reason why you have the old format is because the packages (like the one you used to install on Ubuntu) have not been moved to the YAML format yet. The ticket to switch them is complete ([SERVER-14750](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14750)), so you will get the new format in 3.2.  The file that will be in 3.2 can be [found here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.conf).

For reference, you can find the old format documentation in the [2.4 docs here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/).

If you would like some examples of the YAML configs, I've written up a few common ones [over on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82592/6441).